# how do i update configuration in kotlin for change language on radio btn selected in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, locale, deprecated

how to update this one without using **resources.updateConfiguration** this commented codes please any can say? and solve it.

when i click th eradio btn an dthe language will have to change

this is mainActivity.kt file

```
class LanguageChange : AppCompatActivity() {
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_language_change)
        radio_group_btn.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, i ->
            when(i){
                R.id.radio_btn_fr_id -> {
                   setLang("fr")
                    txt_view1_id.setText(R.string.view_one)
                    txt_view2_id.setText(R.string.view_two)
                    Log.i("tag","french")
                }
                R.id.radio_btn_en_id -> {
                    setLang("en")
                    txt_view1_id.setText(R.string.view_one)
                    txt_view2_id.setText(R.string.view_two)
                    Log.i("tag","english")
                }
            }
        }
    }
  


  private fun Context.setLang(lan: String): Context{
//        val config = resources.configuration
//        config.setLocale(Locale(lan))
//        resources.updateConfiguration(config,resources.displayMetrics)
//        onConfigurationChanged(config)
        val  config = resources.configuration
        config.setLocale(Locale(lan))
        config.setLayoutDirection(Locale(lan))
        applyOverrideConfiguration(config)
       return createConfigurationContext(config)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
        super.attachBaseContext(ContextWrapper(newBase?.setLang("en")))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a good question. Short answer you can't. Even with updateConfiguration you can't be sure about result. For more details please read this article https://medium.com/swlh/android-app-specific-language-change-programmatically-using-kotlin-d650a5392220. But i say it again there is no 100% method to change language inside app with default strings.

Comment: bro its not working.. please tell for my requirement. how to use the  createConfigurationContext  and baseContext how to implement it please tell bro